# How to find an eigenvector given eigenvalue 1, minimising memory use

Tags: memory, optimization, octave, eigenvector

I'd be grateful if people could help me find an efficient way (probably low memory algorithm) to tackle the following problem.

I need to find the stationary distribution `x` of a transition matrix `P`. The transition matrix is an extremely large, extremely sparse matrix, constructed such that all the columns sum to 1. Since the stationary distribution is given by the equation `Px = x`, then `x` is simply the eigenvector of `P` associated with eigenvalue 1.

I'm currently using GNU Octave to both generate the transition matrix, find the stationary distribution, and plot the results. I'm using the function `eigs()`, which calculates both eigenvalues and eigenvectors, and it is possible to return just one eigenvector, where the eigenvalue is 1 (I actually had to specify 1.1, to prevent an error). Construction of the transition matrix (using a sparse matrix) is fairly quick, but finding the eigenvector gets increasingly slow as I increase the size, and I'm running out of memory before I can examine even moderately sized problems.

My current code is

```
[v l] = eigs(P, 1, 1.01);
x = v / sum(v);
```

Given that I know that 1 is the eigenvalue, I'm wondering if there is either a better method to calculate the eigenvector, or a way that makes *more efficient use of memory*, given that I don't really need an intermediate large dense matrix. I naively tried

```
n = size(P,1);       % number of states
Q = P - speye(n,n);
x = Q\zeros(n,1);    % solve (P-I)x = 0
```

which fails, since Q is singular (by definition).

I would be very grateful if anyone has any ideas on how I should approach this, as it's a calculation I have to perform a great number of times, and I'd like to try it on larger and more complex models if possible.

As background to this problem, I'm solving for the equilibrium distribution of the number of infectives in a cattle herd in a stochastic SIR model. Unfortunately the transition matrix is very large for even moderately sized herds. For example: in an SIR model with an average of 20 individuals (95% of the time the population is between 12 and 28 individuals), `P` is 21169 by 21169 with 20340 non-zero values (i.e. 0.0005% dense), and uses up 321 Kb (a full matrix of that size would be 3.3 Gb), while for around 50 individuals `P` uses 3 Mb. `x` itself should be pretty small. I suspect that `eigs()` has a dense matrix somewhere, which is causing me to run out of memory, so I should be okay if I can avoid using full matrices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Power iteration is a standard way to find the dominant eigenvalue of a matrix.  You pick a random vector `v`, then hit it with `P` repeatedly until you stop seeing it change very much.  You want to periodically divide v by `sqrt(v^T v)` to normalise it.

The rate of convergence here is proportional to the separation between the largest eigenvalue and the second largest eigenvalue.  Each iteration takes just a couple of matrix multiplies.

There are fancier-pants ways to do this ("PageRank" is one good thing to search for here) that improve speed for really huge sparse matrices, but I don't know that they're necessary or useful here.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying it right now (ignore my previous comment, I realised it could still be useful even if I've already got the eigenvalue, as I'm pretty sure that the largest eigenvalue is already 1).

Right now I'm starting my initial `x` as `ones(n,1)/n` (where `P` is n by n), and repeatedly multiplying by `P`, so the memory requirements don't balloon (they would if I tried `P` to some power, as the number of non-zero elements rapidly increases). I'll report back if it works better than before.

Comment: Of course the largest few eigenvalues for a small case are 1, .9927, .9818, .9676, ... so the convergence may take a while.

Comment: The largest eigenvalue HAS to be 1 (aside from numerical error), or the equilibrium distribution would either blow up to infinity or disappear to zero.  See the section on "Convergence speed" in this article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain

Comment: Your approach is right.  A gap of 0.007 is plenty big enough for this to converge reasonably in a few thousand iterations---i.e. a second or two on modern hardware.  If the gap gets too small (say `1e-6` or worse), power iteration will become unreasonably slow.  Of course, finding the dominant eigenvector becomes increasingly ill-conditioned, and I don't know why you'd care too much about the answer.

Comment: @tmyklebu: another question, you're letting 'x_{n+1} = P^T P x_{n}'. Can you say why you used the transpose? Having tested it, it does improve convergence speed, but leads to a different end result.

Comment: @spaceLem: Oops.  That was brain fart.  You get the first singular vector with that iteration, but you're looking for the first eigenvector.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach seems like a good one.  However, what you're calling `x`, is the null space of Q.  null(Q) would work if it supported sparse matrices, but it doesn't.  There's a bunch of stuff on the web for finding the null space of a sparse matrix.  For example:

http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/249467

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/42922-null-space-for-sparse-matrix/content/nulls.m

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/11120-null-space-of-a-sparse-matrix

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at those. Right now I'm trying the other suggestion, but this might well end up better for a long term solution (and serve as a useful dusting for my linear algebra skills!).

Answer (score 1):

It seems the best solution is to use the **Power Iteration method**, as suggested by tmyklebu.

The method is to iterate `x = Px; x /= sum(x)`, until `x` converges. I'm assuming convergence if the d1 norm between successive iterations is less than 1e-5, as that seems to give good results.

Convergence can take a while, since the largest two eigenvalues are fairly close (the number of iterations needed to converge can vary considerably, from around 200 to 2000 depending on the model used and population sizes, but it gets there in the end). However, the memory requirements are low, and it's very easy to implement.